# nodejs + nodemon + forever give me an error

Tags: node.js, forever, nodemon

I just installed forever globally (-g). Before that I used to run with

```
$ npm start
```

Now after installed forever, I tried to lunch the node app

```
$ NODE_ENV=development forever nodemon server.js
```

but I receive this error

```
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at     least 1000ms
error:   Cannot start forever
error:   script /path/to/app/nodemon does not exist.
```

the same also with

```
$ NODE_ENV=development forever nodemon server.js
```

any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error you received in your output:

> error:   script /path/to/app/nodemon does not exist.

It appears that forever is looking for nodemon in the current working directory, and can't find it because it doesn't exist there. Try providing the absolute path when starting nodemon, which can be found with `which nodemon`.

```
forever start /usr/local/bin/nodemon server.js
```

Note that the `start` flag is what puts the application in daemon mode.

Comment: ok, I just lunch: **sudo npm install nodemon -g** and it made the installation process. after that there is the same error :(

Comment: /usr/local/bin/nodemon

Comment: Try launching with something like `forever /usr/local/bin/nodemon server.js`. If that doesn't work, try putting `start` as a flag after `forever`.

Comment: ok, now i don't receive any errors. thanks man!
but if I close the terminal, the app doesn't work anymore..
shouldn't it run "forever"?

Comment: Actually, are you using the `start` flag? It is required to start the application in daemon mode, which will keep it online when your terminal is closed. Then use `forever list` to check it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37390/discussion-between-codegirl-and-hexacyanide)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
NODE_ENV=development forever start -c nodemon server.js
```

The ***-c*** is for execute commands, forever send you that error because it's looking for a app called nodeamon, but your app is server.js